# Is good to use a CardLayout to switch between a login pane and a working pane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, cardlayout

I'm learning Swing. I have a `JFrame` which `JPanel` containers - layout is a `CardLayout`. Right now, when you fill the user and password fields, the panel switches and the "working" one is displayed.

I want to add one more panel for selecting a few options before you get into the working pane.

```
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
setLayout(cl);
loginPane = new LoginPanel();
devicePane = new DevicePanel();
workingPane = new WorkingPanel();

add(loginPane,"1");
add(devicePane,"2");
add(workingPane, "3");
```

`LoginPanel`, `DevicePanel` and `WorkingPanel` are all Java classes that extend `JPanel`.

Is this a good practice to follow or should I consider to do something else? Because I'm starting to see that I'll have to create listener from these panels to communicate the frame what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is good to use a `CardLayout` to switch between a login pane and a working pane?"

Yes. In fact, unless it makes sense to include on or more of the panels in a dialog (`JDialog` or `JOptionPane`), a `CardLayout` is the way to go.

> I'm starting to see that I'll have to create listener from these panels to communicate the frame what to do.

The problem here is extending components that likely do not need to be extended. By that I mean, `LoginPanel`, `DevicePanel` & `WorkingPanel` should all be plain `JPanel` instances. By extending panel, the code likely has encapsulated components & listeners which should all be part of one class.

Doing it as one class would negate the problem, as all the components and listeners would have the same scope (& reachability).

Comment: But they do different things, I couldn't justify to specifiy those 3 JPanels actions in the same JFrame class just to set the CardLayout, right? I mean, I rather use 3 different Listeners to talk towards the JFrame to decide which JPanel to show and keep the LoginPanel DevicePanel and WorkingPanel, than mix the functionallity of the LoginPanel with the WorkingPanel in the same class.
Thanks for your answer though :).